# Installation type option "Something else" not shown during Ubuntu 20.04 dual install with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, nvidia

I am new to Ubuntu as OS although I have worked on Linux. I have Windows 10 installed in C: drive and have plenty of unused space in my laptop (Dell XPS 15Z L511Z). I wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a dual boot mode along with Windows.

[Windows Disk Management:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1uPG.png)

I used "Try Ubuntu" option instead of "Install Ubuntu" and it worked just fine. However, since I have a NVIDIA Graphic Card (NVDIA GeForce GT 525M) I had to

```
      1. edit the install command and add "i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa" to it ( as in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it ), and

      2. press F6 and select "nomodeset" and "acpi=off" options in order to make the installation work.
```

Now, I want to actually install it, but when I edit the install option as mentioned above, I am not getting the Installation type option "Something else" - which I get when I do the installation in Graphical mode (i.e. when I'm not editing the install command line, as stated above). I need this option, as I want to create & install Ubuntu in a different partition than Windows (instead of shrinking the Windows partition).

How can I edit the install command & still be able to create the Ubuntu partitions (root, swap & home) myself?

Edit (19-05-2020):

@Nmath: Yes, I was talking about the Graphical Installer only. And, finally I got the "something else" option after pressing F10 (to save the edit that I made in the install command parameters & restart). I was not doing this before & that was the issue.

@waktheboss: Yes, I had enough free un-partitioned space (~300 GB). And, I was able to partition them during the install itself (by selecting the "something else" option).

Thank you both. Anyway, finally I was able to install it & its running fine - except that now, my CPU fan is not at all running (which seems to be a known issue, but I couldn't get a fix yet) & the temperature is always above 80 degrees. I think I should open a new question for that.

Comment: It could be that you have Win 10 pro and full disk encryption.  But since you could boot the live disk you then know your way around a bit. My suggestiion is that if you have encrypting you turn it off or know and backup ten times the key. Then partition from Windows(Easus home edition is great).  Make an ext3/ext4 partition and then try the install again.